# Xtics too close together with GnuPlot and lots of datapoints

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to graph roughly 15k different data points. I have tried all of the different variations that I can think of to reduce the number of xtics, but I can't seem to change the frequency that they are drawn.

Here's my gnuplot file:

```
reset
# need to call with two variables -e "filename='...'" -e "machine='...'"
set title machine." Activity ".filename
set datafile separator ","
set autoscale x
set autoscale y
set autoscale y2
set yrange [0:*]
set y2range [0:*]
set y2tics
set style data lines
set ylabel "% CPU"
set xlabel "Time"
set y2label "Memory (MB)"
set bmargin 7 # room for the xtic label
set term pngcairo size 960,720
set output filename.".png"
# I've also tried autofreq and explicit labels
set xtics axis out rotate 90 scale 0.5 (20101939, 1000000, 25102219)
plot filename \
  using 2:xtic(1) title "CPU" with points pt 1 axes x1y1, \
  "" using ($3 / 1024 / 1024):xtic(1) title "Memory" with points pt 1 axes x1y2
```

The format of my data is:

```
datetime(ddHHMMss), %cpu, mem-in-bytes, pid, process-alias, process-name
```

My data looks like the following (roughly sampled every 30 seconds for 15k records):

```
20101939,0,137932800,6172,process-alias,process-name
20102009,0.15623667978147077,139509760,6172,process-alias,process-name
20102039,0.15623669540380838,139866112,6172,process-alias,process-name
20102109,0.41663098777764329,141488128,6172,process-alias,process-name
20102139,0.052078915131769939,141455360,6172,process-alias,process-name
```

Despite my xtics command with explicit start, interval, and end, my graph always ends up with the xtic labels being overlapped. Here's what it looks like:

[image: graph with overlapping xtic labels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter the tic labels, replace `xtic(1)` with a criterion for printing a non-blank label.  For example, this will print every 25th label.

```
 plot filename \
   using 2:xtic( int($0)%25 ? "" : strcol(1) ) title "CPU" with points pt 1
```

int($0) is the line number; strcol(1) is the content of column 1 read as a string